How to patch drywall flush to the attic door without using molding?
I recently installed a new attic ladder and am considering patching the drywall instead of covering it with molding. I’ve done some research and found options like J-bead. Do you have any suggestions for better methods? Thanks

Right now the attic door frame is flush with the drywall. Can you reinstall it like 1/2" recessed into the ceiling? I think you need a molding detail to prevent damage to the drywall while closing up the gaps. One option is to use a flush molding, like flush baseboard, and cut away the drywall, and transition into the molding with a little z-channel piece specially built for this kind of "flush trim" installation.

The moulding is probably normally included there for practical considerations. Slamming the trap door and/or movement related to using the ladder may cause cracking in the drywall finish where it meets with the ladder components. J-Bead can work, but it may not perform as expected over time and a good air seal will be harder to obtain.
